# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm having a problem with logging in that I didn't have before.  Up until today I was able to log in with no issues.  Suddenly, when I try to log in I get:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
def handle_unverified_request
  raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
end
```

Here's the development log:

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kLm2udi5jHmIQbva2h1HH9IExxFo1qt/p1u9UTjtBQaeHr/23gcrSfTyJdRvhIKYJWh/MyUbSY2zf0vHU8qA9A==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Mack", "username"=>"johnmack", "email"=>"john@mack.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "avatar_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:181:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:209:in `handle_unverified_request'
  devise (3.4.1) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:251:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:204:in `verify_authenticity_token'
```

Up until an couple hours ago I had no trouble logging in and out.  I've tried clearing browser data, logging in from multiple browsers, restarting the server, dropping and recreating the db, and reverting my code back to what it was two days ago.  I get the same error.

I'm using Rails 4.2 and Devise 3.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, you are missing CSRF token. It seems you are using a ajax request or you build non rails form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up tracing the issue to how I was setting the session store to enable cross subdomain authentication.  Originally I had this:

```
HeartbeatPods::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_Heartbeat-pods_session', domain: ENV["HEARTBEAT_HOSTNAME"], tld_length: 2
```

I changed it to this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
    Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_Heartbeat-pods_session', domain: :all
else
    Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_Heartbeat-pods_session'
end
```

The original solution supported cross subdomain auth on my local system but ended up borking.  The updated solution only supports cross subdomain auth on the production set up.